# Clear current text area only

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to clear the the text field after an AJAX POST request submission.
Here is the relevant JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chat-send").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data,
            success : function( data ) {
                alert('Submitted' + data);
            },
            error : function( xhr, err ) {
                alert('Error' + err);
                // CLEAR FIELD
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The processing script doesn't exist yet, so to test I'm testing on error instead of success.

The HTML form has class `chat-send` and the text area has class `messagearea`. I tried doing it without a `messagearea` class, and then added that in, but that hasn't helped so far.

Everything else about this is tested and works. I'm having trouble with the **clear field** part.

Here are just some of the things I've tried:

```
$(this).find(".messagearea").val("");
$(this).closest("form").trigger( "reset" );
$(this).closest("form").find(".messagearea").val("");
$(this).children().filter(".messagearea").val("");
$(this).find('.messagearea').empty();
```

And many more variations on these, as well.

The only thing that actually has an effect is this, which is the most *common* (and also useless in this case) answer:

```
$(".messagearea").val("");
```

And that is **not** what I want, since it clears **all** the text areas with that class.

I think my efforts are being thrwarted because I'm not chaining downwards from *this* properly, but other examples seem to indicate these approaches should work, including other accepted answers on SO.

How can I select the text area in question using jQuery to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your AJAX error handling function has a differently scoped `this` than your submit handler.

To fix that, simply create and use a closure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chat-send").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method");
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        const form = this; // definition of a block scoped variable
        $.ajax({
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data,
            success : function( data ) {
                alert('Submitted' + data);
            },
            error : function( xhr, err ) {
                alert('Error' + err);
                // CLEAR FIELD
                $(form).find(".messagearea").val(""); // which makes it available here as a closure
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `error` callback `this` refers to the jqXhr object not the form.

You can use arrow function notation to keep the context (this) of the outer function in the error callback

```
        error : ( xhr, err ) => {
            alert('Error' + err);
            $(this).find(".messagearea").val("");
        }
```

Alternately you can set the context of your ajax request so that in all callbacks the `this` is set to whatever you want

```
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data,
        context: this, //i.e. the form
        success : function( data ) {
            alert('Submitted' + data);
        },
        error : function( xhr, err ) {
            alert('Error' + err);
            $(this).find(".messagearea").val(""); // also the form
        }
```